# How to pass function value and set it to another variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a flag `sendMessageFlag` if its true i want to set function obj to `fileData` but it always says *undefined*.

**ctrl.js**

```
var sendMessageFlag;

function sendMessageToFile (data){
    return data;
}

socket.on('ditConsumer',function (data) {
     var obj = {
         file:$scope.filename,
         data:data
     }

     if(sendMessageFlag) {
         console.log('send messageto FIe in consumer');
         sendMessageToFile(obj);
     }
});

if($scope.filename) {
     sendMessageFlag = true;
     var fileData = sendMessageToFile(data);
     console.log('CONSUMER MESSAGE', fileData);
     socket.emit('startrecording', fileData);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, which variable is becoming undefined?

Comment: Where is the `data` params on this line `var fileData = sendMessageToFile(data);` coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the value of sendMessageFlag when you declare the variable up top. If socket.on('ditConsumer') gets fired first, the value is undefined. You might want to initialize it with false and then set it to true later in the if block at the bottom.

Comment: if block is executing when value is true only problem is function value is not setting to `fileData`

Comment: You got a point, though im not familiar with `socket` when does `socket.on()` being fired?

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood correctly, below is the solution (so that you don't get undefined in 'console.log('CONSUMER MESSAGE', fileData);' :

```
if(sendMessageFlag) {
     console.log('send messageto FIe in consumer');
     return sendMessageToFile(obj);
}
```

You should also return from the if condition.